# Is it possible to use a json file to seed a supabase postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I want to use a json file as single source of truth for my database seeds and my end-to-end tests (to control the database state and compare it to test state).

The seed is applied with "supabase db reset" locally and then with "supabase db push --include-all" remote.

The following code works:

```
WITH
    notification_json (doc) AS (
        VALUES
            ('[
                {
                    "sender": "42e58ca1-2eb8-4651-93c2-cefba2e32f42",
                    "receiver": "f8b028b8-231b-4c80-abf2-7ca787fe686f",
                    "type_of_notification": "follow_from_user",
                    "read_by_receiver": "FALSE"
                }
            ]'::json)
    )
INSERT
INTO
    authenticated_access.notifications_by_user (sender,
                                                receiver,
                                                type_of_notification,
                                                read_by_receiver)
SELECT
    n.sender,
    n.receiver,
    n.type_of_notification,
    n.read_by_receiver
FROM
    notification_json l
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL JSON_POPULATE_RECORDSET(
        NULL::authenticated_access.notifications_by_user,
        doc) AS n;
```

But if I try to load the JSON from a separate file with `PG_READ_FILE('./notifications.json')` then the code fails with the error:

```
ERROR: could not open file "notifications.json" for reading: No such file or directory (SQLSTATE 58P01)
```

While this means, that the file does not exist, I checked it and the file does exist and the directory structure looks like this:

```
supabase
- migrations
  - seed.sql
  - notifications.json
```

The following code does not work:

```
WITH
    notification_json (doc) AS (
        VALUES
            ((
                SELECT PG_READ_FILE('./notifications.json')
            )::json)
    )
INSERT
INTO
    authenticated_access.notifications_by_user (sender,
                                                receiver,
                                                type_of_notification,
                                                read_by_receiver)
SELECT
    n.sender,
    n.receiver,
    n.type_of_notification,
    n.read_by_receiver
FROM
    notification_json l
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL JSON_POPULATE_RECORDSET(
        NULL::authenticated_access.notifications_by_user,
        doc) AS n;
```

What is wrong here? Might it be the issue that the engine executing the SQL does not have access to the local/repository files anymore?

Is there a better approach to keep seed and test data in sync?

Comment: Have you read this section *9.27.9. Generic File Access Functions* from here [Admin Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html)?

Comment: Try reading the JSON file content in your application or script and then pass the content to your SQL query. This approach works well in both development and production environments, as it doesn't rely on the PostgreSQL server having access to your local files.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have not. But after reading it now, I still do not understand if the machine hosting the supabase postgre database has access to my json files.

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com How do I do that? The code snippet mentioned above is the migration script. There is no additional application code.

Comment: You have not said where the JSON files are located? If they are not on the server machine and accessible to the server then they will not be reachable by `PG_READ_FILE`.

Comment: It's because I am not sure if the server has access to the files. The files are on my local machine. The postgres database is on a local docker-desktop or a remote server. Then I apply the migration to the local and remote database (https://supabase.com/docs/guides/cli/local-development). Following your argumentation, my conclusion is, that the CLI command adds the migration SQL scripts to the docker and remote database without the json files, executes it there and both databases have no access to my local file system.

Comment: This file is not mounted to the docker instance so there is no way for it to be read there. The suggestion by @TSCAmerica.com is the way to go in your case.

Comment: But I do not understand how @TSCAmerica.com approach works. How do I read a json file into a SQL script?

Comment: Write a script in a language like Python, Node.js, or PHP that can fetch the JSON data from an HTTP URL or a local file. The script can then parse this JSON data and insert it into your PostgreSQL database using appropriate database queries. OR

you can use a command like COPY table_name FROM PROGRAM 'curl http://example.com/data.json'; to load data from a web URL. Note that this requires the PostgreSQL server to have access to the curl command and permission to execute it, which might not be allowed in many server environments.